# i can't insert multiselect jquery value into database

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-2, multi-select

i use jquery multiselect to show my data

this is how i show my data on my view

---

```
<td><select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="id_c[]">
        <?php foreach ($test as $data): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $data->id_a ?>" ><?php echo $data->nama ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select><td>
```

---

and this how i save into database in my model

```
function save(){    

        $id_c= $this->input->post('id_c');
        var_dump($id_c);
        $idb = '';
        $count = count($id_c);
        $i=0;
        foreach($id_c as $e){
            if($i < $count -1){
                $idb .= $e.', ';
            }else{
                $idb .= $e;
            }
            $i++;
        }

            $tanggal = $this->input->post('tanggal');
            $data=array(
                        'id_c'=>$idb,
                        'tanggal'=>$tanggal
                        );
            $this->db->insert('detail',$data);
    }
```

but when i click submit the value didn't go into database

i try to use var_dump and this what i get
bool(false)

---

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: try to print `$this->input->post()` using print_r() function and check whether you are getting posted data or not.

Comment: Where's the jQuery / JS code that applies to the select element?

Comment: i use jquery multiselect and i just put it in my <head></head> and call it in my form class="multiselect"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your save method should looks like:

```
function save(){    
    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($this->input->post()); //first try to check whether you are receiving posted data or not.
    //die;

    $id_c= $this->input->post('id_c');
    $idb = implode(',', $id_c);
    $tanggal = $this->input->post('tanggal');
        $data=array(
                    'id_c'=>$idb,
                    'tanggal'=>$tanggal
                    );
        $this->db->insert('detail', $data);
}
```

Comment: i try your code and i get this error

Column 'id_c' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `detail` (`id_c`, `tanggal`) VALUES (NULL, 0)

Comment: i get this Array
(
    [simpan] => simpan
)

Comment: Have you realized that you are trying to get `$this->input->post('id_c')` and `$this->input->post('tanggal')` and it doesn't exist. There might something wrong with your html. Kindly check and verify.